# How to setup jsdom when working with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom, ava

I'm trying to migrate from AVA to Jest. In AVA you can set `ava.setup`, in which you set the `jsdom` environment. For example, creating the DOM structure and doing necessary polyfills (localStorage).

How do I accomplish that in Jest? Currently, I'm using `beforeEach` in each test suite, which doesn't feel like the best solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Great question.

Jest actually ships with `jsdom` and the environment already configured. You can override it with the `testEnvironment` [setting](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string).

If you need to set up more aspects of the environment though, you can use the `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` [setting](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string) to point to a file that executes before all of your tests run.

For example, if you need `window.yourVar` to be available on the window for all your tests, you would add this to your `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "tests/setup.js"
}
```

And in tests/setup.js:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'yourVar', { value: 'yourValue' });
```

Comment: I knew about the testEnvironment and default value but the 'setupTestFrameworkScriptFile' was what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: one more thing, not totally related, which expect package do you recommend? I must have a custom message and jest-expect doesnt provide this option.

Comment: If you want to include a message I'd recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect

Comment: `setupFilesAfterEnv` is recommended now.

Answer (score 12):

Update 2022. Version **28** does not ship jsdom by default anymore:

*As of Jest 28 "jsdom" is no longer shipped by default, make sure to install it separately.*

You'll need to install jsdom manually:

```
# npm
npm install -D jest-environment-jsdom
# yarn
yarn add jest-environment-jsdom
```

credit to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72013609/7089048

Comment: should it be `npm install --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom`?

Comment: Absolutely, updated accordingly. 

Comment: ... and `yarn add -D jest-environment-jsdom`