# Jest - react - how to compare a rendered output that includes "Function onClick"

Tags: reactjs

When I have

```
expect(result.toJSON())
.toEqual(<button className="btn btn-prev" onClick="{[Function onClick]}" type="button">Prev</button>);
```

it is close but not quite right - just missing the `Function onClick`:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
- Expected
+ Received

  <button
    className="btn btn-prev"
-   onClick="{[]}"
+   onClick={[Function onClick]} // <--- the difference, Function onClick is missing
    type="button"
  >
    Prev
  </button>
```

However if I try and add in the missing "`Function onClick`", i.e.

```
expect(result.toJSON())
.toEqual(<button className="btn btn-prev" onClick="{[Function onClick]}" type="button">Prev</button>);
```

I get

```
-   onClick="{[Function onClick]}"
+   onClick={[Function onClick]}
```

and if I remove the quotes i get a parsing error at onClick !

What is the right way to deal with this issue which must be a problem for others

Comment: Are you trying to write [snapshot tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing)? Note that they are not high quality tests, they just detect implementation changes and tell you very little about behaviour. For this specific issue [Function onClick] is the *representation* of a function that was passed as the prop value, not an actual value you can compare - `onClick="{[Function onClick]}"` makes no sense as a prop for the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jest` is just a test runner and mocking tool. It can not accesses your react components.

You can try [Enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) lib which is for React.

And you can do something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from './someComponent'

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  const someClickFunc = Jest.fn();
  it('renders xxx components', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(xxx)).to.have.lengthOf(x);
  });

  it('simulates click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent onClick={someClicFunc} />);
    wrapper.find(MyComponent).simulate('click');
    expect(someClicFunc).toBeCalled();
    // or find the target dom and compare the value
    // expect(wrapper.find('input').value).toEqaul('somevalue u expected')
  });
```

Comment: Would this be the right way to verify the entire HTMl (that the JSX produces) for that component.  i.e. would I be able to `expect` against the final entire output for that component.

Comment: Is jsdom also an option here?

Comment: probably here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970780/how-to-setup-jsdom-when-working-with-jest @MichaelDurrant

Answer (score 0):

The test is failing because `{[Function onClick]}` is the string *representation* of the `onClick` method, but it isn't actually a string that is rendered. You need to compare the `onClick` to an actual function during that test.

While you can create a mock of the `onClick` and use it in the assertion, it is not required. If you do not need (or want) mock the `onClick` functionality: use [`expect.any(Function)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectanyconstructor). This will signal to `jest` that a function is being passed but not require it to be mocked.

For instance, this test will render your component (I'm calling it `<PreviousButton>`), and get the rendered JSX/TSX. It then asserts that the rendered button has the proper `className` and `type` while allowing any function to be passed as the `onClick` method.

```js
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';

describe('Previous Button', () => {
  test('renders clickable button', () => {
    const wrapper = ShallowRenderer.createRenderer();
    wrapper.render(<PreviousButton />);

    const result = wrapper.getRenderOutput();
    expect(result).toEqual([
      <button className="btn btn-prev" onClick={expect.any(Function)} type="button">Prev</button>
    ]);
  });
});
```

I used the [Shallow Renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/shallow-renderer.html) from the React Testing Library (17.0.2+) since it now recommended over Enzyme for later versions of React. `react-test-renderer` needs to be installed via `npm`/`yarn` before use.