# How can I fix this error "ReferenceError: ImageData is not defined" when using agora-rtc-sdk-ng and running Jest unit tests?

Tags: angular, jestjs, agora.io

I am using the agora web sdk (agora-rtc-sdk-ng Version 4.8.2 from npm) as an import in an angular project. The sdk works fine and can be used just like expected. But when I try to run tests with Jest I get the following error message: **"ReferenceError: ImageData is not defined"** for the following Import statement

`import AgoraRTC, { IAgoraRTCRemoteUser } from 'agora-rtc-sdk-ng';`

Has anyone experienced the same or has any idea how to fix this error?

Here is the complete error message:

````
FAIL  src/app/modules/news/components/news-article/news-article.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: ImageData is not defined

      11 | import { selectUserProfile } from '@core/selectors/user.selectors';
      12 | import { AppState } from '@core/reducers';
    > 13 | import AgoraRTC, { IAgoraRTCRemoteUser } from 'agora-rtc-sdk-ng';
         | ^
      14 | import { UserProfile } from '@core/models/user.model';
      15 |
      16 | export interface Meeting {

      at node_modules/agora-rtc-sdk-ng/AgoraRTC_N-production.js:17:65778
      at node_modules/agora-rtc-sdk-ng/AgoraRTC_N-production.js:5:84
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/agora-rtc-sdk-ng/AgoraRTC_N-production.js:5:203)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/core/services/meeting.service.ts:13:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/shared/components/meeting/meeting.component.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/shared/components/index.ts:32:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/shared/shared.module.ts:7:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/reactions/reactions.module.ts:7:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/modules/news/components/news-article/news-article.component.spec.ts:16:1)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) isn't part of the test environment used by Jest. You can create a mock definition for ImageData yourself. You can use the `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` setting to point to a file that executes before all of your tests run as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983837/6067894).

For example, if you need `window.ImageData` to be available on the window add this to your `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "tests/setup.js"
}
```

And in `tests/setup.js`:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'ImageData', { value: 'yourValue' });
```

Alternatively, you can expect the error and handle it in your test.