global.window is undefined after upgrading Jest
We had a dependabot pull which is upgrading jest, jest-cli and braces from the following versions:
Updates `braces` from 3.0.2 to 3.0.3
- [Changelog](https://github.com/micromatch/braces/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
- [Commits](micromatch/braces@3.0.2...3.0.3)

Updates `jest` from 26.6.3 to 29.7.0
- [Release notes](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/releases)
- [Changelog](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)
- [Commits](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/commits/v29.7.0/packages/jest)

Updates `jest-cli` from 26.6.3 to 29.7.0
- [Release notes](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/releases)
- [Changelog](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)
- [Commits](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/commits/v29.7.0/packages/jest-cli)

We have a testSetup.jsx file which gets included from the jest.config.js file:
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
    '<rootDir>/testSetup.jsx'
  ],

Unfortunately after the upgrade anything referencing global.window is failing as it is saying that window is undefined. So for example the testSetup.jsx file fails on the following line:

    TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ApptentiveSDK')

      117 | }
      118 | */
    > 119 | global.window.ApptentiveSDK = { createConversation: jest.fn(() => { }), engage: jest.fn(() => { }) }
          |                            ^
      120 |
      121 | global.CSS = { supports: jest.fn() }
      122 |


I'm not sure where to start digging for this one. If anyone can give me some direction it would be greatly appreciated.

So the issue appears to be that jsdom https://stackoverflow.com/a/72996199/1348329 is not the default starting with jest 28. I had to set the testEnvironment config to 'jsdom' and install npm install --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom
